# Extract number from string in python without re

Tags: python, string, int, extract

How can I extract a number from a string in python without having to use regex? I have seen `isinstance` but the number could change to almost anything. Any ideas?

`https://www.investopedia.com/articles/retirement/?page=6`

Comment: Well, you're just reading from a query string in that case... parse it out and read the `page` parameter...

Comment: [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) documentation for parsing url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes that there isn't multiple blocks of integers (e.g. `www.something212.com/page=?13`)

You could try using list comprehensions and `str.isdigit()`

```
url = 'https://www.investopedia.com/articles/retirement/?page=6'

digits = [d for d in url if d.isdigit()]

digit = ''.join(digits)

digit
>>> 6
```

Edited: now works with digits above 9

Comment: what happens if that 6 is 12?

Comment: digits would produce `[6,12]`. You could join the answer by using `number = ''.join(map(int, digits))`

Comment: I know, I'm saying why not address that in your answer?

Comment: you could just `''.join(digits)` since you already know whats in there

Comment: running `''.join(digits)` on a list containing integers throws an error.

Comment: yeah i didnt notice you brought them in as `int`

Comment: I like it now, looks like something I would do :)

Comment: i like it better than my own solution actually

Comment: Please accept the answer if it has solved your query

Comment: @vash_the_stampede I’m gonna have to agree with you. This is a pretty good bit of code.

Comment: @Kamikaze_goldfish yeah he skipped the appending processes, and got same result, very nice

Comment: @vash_the_stampede you must live in here

Comment: @Kamikaze_goldfish ... ;)

Comment: this assumes the entire url and querystring doesn't have any other digits in it.  that's a pretty gratuitous assumption.

Comment: @wim it usually doesn’t. If it does then I’ll come back and try your code out. I’m just out from my computer so I can’t check it.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit verbose, but I would use url parsing for this.  The advantage overy regex is that you would get some input validation for free, and more readable code.

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs
>>> url = 'https://www.investopedia.com/articles/retirement/?page=6'
>>> parsed = urlparse(url)
>>> query = parse_qs(parsed.query)
>>> [page] = query['page']
>>> int(page)
6
```

Answer (score 2):

You can extract continuous groups of digits, anywhere on the string, using the following:

```
from itertools import groupby

url = 'https://www.investopedia.com/articles/retirement/?page=6&limit=10&offset=15'
print([int(''.join(group)) for key, group in groupby(iterable=url, key=lambda e: e.isdigit()) if key])
```

**Output**

```
[6, 10, 15]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `url` always has that format with only digits at the end you could do this:

```
s = 'https://www.investopedia.com/articles/retirement/?page=25'
new = []
k = list(s)
[new.append(i) for i in k if i.isdigit()]
print(''.join(new))
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 isdigit.py
> 25
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I know you do not need `re`, but it is actually very powerful.  Under the hood, most libraries make use of `re`. Here is my solution to handle this situation:

```
import re

url = "www.fake888.com/article/?article=123&page=9&group=8"

numbers = re.findall(r'(?<==)(\d+)', url)
print(f'Found: {" ".join(numbers)}')

varval = re.findall(r'(\w+)=(\d+)', url)
urldict = {}
for var in varval:
  urldict[var[0]] = var[1]

print(urldict)
```

The output is

```
Found: 123 9 8
{'article': '123', 'page': '9', 'group': '8'}
```

Comment: I’m gonna have to check that out! Thanks for the link. I really have wanted to learn regex for a while because of its power. 